# Execute 5 ajax calls at once from a total of n calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I currently have an array of ids I get from an initial ajax call where I need to make subsequent calls.  Let's say there are 20 ids in that array.

What I need to do now is to make 5 calls at once only since we don't want to overload our server.  And once those 5 are complete, start the next 5.  Once its all done I need to console.log('done');

```
var ids = [3,5,2,6,7,13,35,27,8,5,3,5,26,57,18,3,42,67];
var results = {};

var ajaxCall = function(id) {
    $.ajax({ 
       url: '/url?id=' + id, method: 'GET'})
      .complete(function(data) {
           results[id] = data;
      });
}
```

Comment: Are all these calls gonna call same ajax function? if yes then why are you trying to divide the calss to 5 instead of putting as a single call??

Comment: yes same ajax function but different results from the id.

Comment: what happen if only one call will go? use POST and send all at single time and then change your php code from $_GET to $_POST and return result

Comment: i get that different id will get you different results but what am asking you is why dont you make a single call and then return a list of objects with ids and corresponding  results

Comment: I don't have control of the server response.

Comment: @KingKongFrog check my answer below, please mark as a answer if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setInterval` that will check for every `5` AJAX call and on last set of 5 records, `clearInterval` like below code.

Check below sample how you can get set of `5 Ajax call` and `console.log('completed');` after each one is processed.

```
function make5call()
```

Above function will simply request for `next 5` ids from `array`

```
function initTimer()
```

Above timer will check is all `5 Ajax request` are finished then start next `set of 5 request` and if all are completed then `clearInterval`

```js
var ids = [3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 13, 35, 27, 8, 5, 3, 5, 26, 57, 18, 3, 42, 67];
//var ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];

var results = {};
var length = ids.length;
var j = 0;
var pendingAJAX = 5; // Set of ajax call in one go
var complete = false;
var totalCompleted = 0;

// Ajax request function
var ajaxCall = function(id) {
  $.ajax({
      url: '/url?id' + id,
      method: 'GET'
    })
    .complete(function(data) {
      results[id] = data;
      console.log(id);
      pendingAJAX--; //After each complete decrement one
      totalCompleted++; //Track for completed Ajax
      // If all sets are completed and total is also same as your ids
      if (complete && totalCompleted == ids.length) {
        console.log('completed');
      }
    });
}

var make5call = function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // If all Ajax finished set complete to true
    if (j == ids.length) {
      complete = true;
    }
    if (j < ids.length) {
      ajaxCall(ids[j]); //request Ajax
      j++;
    }
  }
}

// Timer to check when to call for next 5 request
var initTimer = function() {

  var timer = null;
  timer = window.setInterval(function() {

    // Either all are completed or 5 Ajax complted clear interval
    if (pendingAJAX == 0 || complete) {
      timer = window.clearInterval(timer);
      timer = null;
      // If All are not finished yet start timer again
      if (!complete) {
        pendingAJAX = 5;
        initTimer();
        make5call();
      }
    }
  }, 100);

}

initTimer();
make5call();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a pool for ajax calls.

```
var ajaxPool = function(length) {
    this.length = length;
    this.ajaxRequests = [];
        this.callbacks = [];
}
$.extend(ajaxPool.prototype, {
    add: function(options) {
        this.ajaxRequests.push({
            options: options
        });
    },
    success: function(callback) {
        this.callbacks.push(callback);
            return this;
    },
    triggerCallback:function(){
        var xthis = this;
        this.callbacks.forEach(function(callback){
        callback.call(this);
      });       
    },
    executeNext: function() {
        var xthis = this;
        var i = 0;
        for ( ;i < this.ajaxRequests.length; i++) {
            if (!this.ajaxRequests[i].executed) {
                                console.log('executing '+i+' request');
                $.ajax(this.ajaxRequests[i].options).complete(function() {
                    xthis.executeNext();
                });
                this.ajaxRequests[i].executed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i==this.ajaxRequests.length && !this.complete){
            this.complete = true;
            this.triggerCallback();
        }
    },
    executeAll: function() {
        if (this.length > this.ajaxRequests.length) {
            this.length = this.ajaxRequests.length;
        }
        var xthis = this;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                        console.log('executing '+i+' request')
            $.ajax(this.ajaxRequests[i].options).complete(function() {
                xthis.executeNext();
            });
            this.ajaxRequests[i].executed = true;
        }
    }
})
```

Then add your params to this pool and start executing requests in chunks

```
var ids = [3,5,2,6,7,13,35,27,8,5,3,5,26,57,18,3,42,67];
var pool = new ajaxPool(5);
//adding a success function when all are completed
pool.success(function(){
    console.log('All Done!!!');
});
var results = {};
ids.forEach(function(id){
    pool.add({ 
       url: '/url?id=' + id, method: 'GET',success:function(data) {
           results[id] = data;
      }})

})
pool.executeAll();
```

### Working Example

https://jsfiddle.net/memsv4fk/

Comment: Nice!  However how do you execute a function when all are complete?

Comment: Updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/memsv4fk/3/  :)
Now ,you can add callback  by using 
`pool.success(function(){
 console.log('All executed!!!');
});`

Answer (score 0):

Well 5 calls at **once** is going to be hard ;) But you can make 5 call sequentially, wait a second (this prevents flooding to the server) between the calls.

These 5 calls should be send with `async: false`, so you are making these (ajax) calls **synchronous**.

If you want this to be **asynchronous**, the waiting effect will be difficult to manage. Since it all depends how fast the calls are processed. It will work, but you should wait *much longer* for it to have some effect.

I would use the remainder function.

```
var ids = [3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 13, 35, 27, 8, 5, 3, 5, 26, 57, 18, 3, 42, 67];

for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  // one ore more ajax calls
  if (i % 5 == 0) {
    // pause
    console.log("do something else 5 calls, i=" + i);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wx9o01e3/2/

Comment: Using async false will make the requests one by one, not five by five.

Comment: @Salketer yeah your absolutely right, I rephrased it. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to use waits, synchronous ajax or intervals... The strategy here would be to fire up 5 ajax manually, and have them fire up another ajax when they are finish. That way you'd have 5 ajax at the same time and won't have to wait for the 5 of them to finish before firing 5 other.

```
var ids = [3,5,2,6,7,13,35,27,8,5,3,5,26,57,18,3,42,67];
var results = {};

var ajaxCall = function(id) {
    $.ajax({url: '/url?id=' + id, method: 'GET'})
      .done(function(data) {
           results[id] = data;
           newAjaxCall();
      }).fail(function(){
           //handle failure if needed.
           //Do not prevent other calls to run so start a new one.
           newAjaxCall();
      });
}
var newAjaxCall = function(){
    if(ids.length>0){
        ajaxCall(ids.shift());
    }
}
//Start the ajax chain;
var ajaxAmount = 5;
for(var i=0;i<ajaxAmount;i++){
    newAjaxCall();
}
```

So, what we do is we have a function that will create the new ajaxCall using the next ID of the array, removes that ID so it is not reused. If the array needs to be kept intact, a clone could do or keeping the index of the next ID could work. I've changed your .complete to .done as it's getting deprecated in jQuery 3.

Once we got everything set up, we create the amount of ajax calls we want.

EDIT: After re-reading OP, it seems you really want to wait for the 5 ajax calls to end before starting 5 others. Although I do understand why you want to process only 5 at one given time, I do not understand why should those 5 finish before continuing... Here's the modified code to achieve that:

```
var ids = [3,5,2,6,7,13,35,27,8,5,3,5,26,57,18,3,42,67];
var results = {};

var ajaxCall = function(id) {
    return $.ajax({url: '/url?id=' + id, method: 'GET'})
      .done(function(data) {
           results[id] = data;
      }).fail(function(){
           //handle failure if needed.
      });
}
var ajaxChain = function(){
    var ajaxAmount = 5;
    var ongoingCalls = 0;

    for(var i=0;i<ajaxAmount;i++){
        if(ids.length>0){
            onGoingCalls++;
            ajaxCall(ids.shift()).always(function(){
                ongoingCalls--;
                if(ongoingCalls == 0){
                    ajaxChain();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
//Start the ajax chain;
ajaxChain();
```